# Java - MySQL query where clause failing when ID added to time

Tags: java, mysql, where-clause

I am looking to search a database of sensor events and remove the events where their timestamp is equal to or minus ten second and whose sensor ID are within a list of approved ID's.

When I run the query with just the time parameter the result set is as expected but when the sensorID parameter is added it seems to be returning all the sensor events that meet the sensorID requirements but ignores the timestamp requirement.

The query:

```
"SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN " + visionTime + " - INTERVAL 10 SECOND AND " + visionTime + " AND sensorID = 34035434 OR sensorID = 34035492 OR sensorID = 34035426 OR sensorID = 34035482 OR sensorID = 34035125 OR sensorID = 34035498 OR sensorID = 34035508 OR sensorID = 34035444 OR sensorID = 34035418 OR sensorID = 34035466 OR sensorID = 34035128 OR sensorID = 34035119 OR sensorID = 34035448 OR sensorID = 34037294 OR sensorID = 34035549;"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parentheses for the `or` conditions something as below. The reason is first it will check the `and` condition and adding multiple or without parentheses after and will satisfy one of the or condition resulting complete ignore of the previous `and`

So it will be more like

```
select * from table where col='a' and col2 = 'b' and (col3 = 'c' or col3 = 'd')
```

The above will return where `col = 'a'` and `col2='b'` and `col3` is either `c or d`

The same thing in your query should be as

```
"SELECT * FROM events 
   WHERE timestamp BETWEEN " + visionTime + " - INTERVAL 10 SECOND 
   AND " + visionTime + "
   AND ( sensorID = 34035434 
    OR sensorID = 34035492 
    OR sensorID = 34035426 
    OR sensorID = 34035482 
    OR sensorID = 34035125 
    OR sensorID = 34035498 
    OR sensorID = 34035508 
    OR sensorID = 34035444 
    OR sensorID = 34035418 
    OR sensorID = 34035466 
    OR sensorID = 34035128 
    OR sensorID = 34035119 
    OR sensorID = 34035448 
    OR sensorID = 34037294 
    OR sensorID = 34035549 
  )"
```

Comment: That worked. Do you mind explaining why this was needed? Was it due to multiple `OR` conditions or multiple `AND`?

Comment: This is because multiple OR conditions. Their boolean value should be evaluated as one entity when used with AND.